# How to undo changes in Visual Studio when syncing with Github using GitHub extensions for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, github, git-extensions

I am trying to get new changes from my fork on GitHub. I have the solution open in Visual Studio 2015 and I am using GitHub extensions for Visual Studio. I am getting a message to commit my changes or undo them. I don't know what these changes are and I want to undo them. How do I find them and undo them? 
I don't see entries in outgoing commits. The Output window is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Git forbids most operations when there are uncommitted changes in your repository. This simply prevents data loss.

You can find all uncommitted changes in the Team Explorer - Changes
There you can Undo all your changes.